# wondering about Negative alpha cronbach

Tags: reliability, cronbachs-alpha

I used a questionnaire that usually has a high Cronbach's alpha and that has a scale of 7 answers.
I did a before and after (an intervention) evaluation and got a very very low alpha for the before and a negative alpha for the after. Since the 20 people who answered the questions do not represent a normal population (they have problems), the mean score for the "before" evaluation was 1.9 and had a very low sd (i.e., all answers for the 6 questions ranged between 1-3 for all participants). The mean score for the "after" evaluation was 5.9 with a low sd once again (ranging between 4-7).

I am sure there were no mistakes in the coding. Could it be that the standard deviation influenced  the results? If not, what other suggestions do you have, and what am I supposed to do with this?

I should point out that the intervention was directed specifically at changing the behaviour we were measuring, so the results other than the alpha are good for us.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: If you look at a formula of alpha you can see that it is based on the ratio of the average inter-item covariance to the average item variance. The sign is therefore determined by the average item covariance. If all items individual scales in a construct are co-oriented there should be no negative covariances.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What I'm wondering is, with these kind of scales, where you have 7 options, the "valence" of answers 1-3 or 5-7 are similar (within each group). If that's the case then the fact that in both evaluations all participants answered in the same "valence" area, then the alpha doesn't really tell us much, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given us the correlations among the items, which would help, but it sounds like you probably have a problem with restriction of range, which would lower correlations and hence alpha.

If this is the case, there is little you can do about it on this sample. But it might not be that bad as the mean rose so much.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yeah, correlations did not come out significant for obvious reasons....So do you think I should just report it as is and give my explanation for it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I think you should do.

Comment: This is a great answer. Here's a paper that shows how easy it is to get negative reliability estimates under range restriction: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0013164411430225